# Accessing core data relationship causes crash when i build then app again, no crash...?

Tags: ios, core-data, exc-bad-access

I have a core data model where i have an Exhibit entity, with some attributes and a one to many relationship with an ExhibitImage entity, when i first populate core data

```
ExhibitImage *exhibitImage = [ExhibitImage init];
exhibitImage.filePath = [self loadFile:imageUrl];
exhibitImage.exhibit = thisExhibit;//this exhibit is a method arguement of type Exhibit*
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[thisExhibit.exhibitImages anyObject] filePath]];
```

I then save the core data

```
+ (BOOL) saveManagedObjectContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![MOC save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Core Data Save Error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Data      Save Failure", @"The application failed to save data to the database")
                                                                 message:error.localizedDescription 
                                                                delegate:nil 
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"BUTTON: OK") 
                                                       otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [errorAlertView show];
    return NO;
}
NSLog(@"CORE DATA SAVED");

return YES;
}
```

and can successfully access the relationship again

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[thisExhibit.exhibitImages anyObject] filePath]];
```

When i later try to access the relationship, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
NSArray *images = [self.exhibit.exhibitImages allObjects];//EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1b)
```

When i run the code again, after the crash, without setting the core data, the line above runs and the images display!

I have no idea as to why this is happening, and have tried everything i know to fix this...
Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:` method of `NSEntityDescription` to create your new ExhibitImage, rather than just a straight `init`?  I think you are creating them on the heap, but not putting them in the database.  Hence they work during each run of your app, but are not preserved between runs.

Comment: Sorry i should've explained, Exhibits are extended and include their own init method which is                                   `+(Exhibit *)init
{
    Exhibit *newEntity = (Exhibit *)[ModelHelper createNewObjectForEntityName:@"Exhibit"];
    
    return newEntity;
}`

Comment: That explains how you got away without an alloc, which had me perplexed!  Have you checked 'self.exhibit' is well-defined (not nil, of correct class, respondsToSelector and the like) just before the line which gives the error?